# Highchart Label alignment on xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have got some issues on xaxis label the dates are overridden the graph with problem is given on the below link
https://postimg.cc/image/4l60kavw7/
I need to make it like below graph
https://postimg.cc/image/tefkkz21z/
Is there any way to align the labels?
I have tried align justify but its not working is that a problem with highchart versions?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with the options you are using?

Comment: sorry i font have the exact jsfiddle code Is there any to align the labels like that? or is that a problem with highchart versions? or do i need to enable any property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't support that functionality. You can program this custom behavior in `render` event by iterating all x axis labels and modifying the y position of some of them.

In `render` event you can get the axis object this way: `this.xAxis[0]`. It contains `ticks` array. Tick object has the `label` property. Label object has a method called `attr` that can be used to alter the vertical position of the label (`label.attr({y: newValue})`). Current position of the label can be found in its `xy` property.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Let me give it a try